# How to write a double summation in Python with multiple variables , I am a new programmer in the data science field

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, formula, equation, data-science-experience

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw3ka.png)

I am a new programmer in the Data field and need help to write in Python

Comment: please do not post images. many of people do watch SO on mobile. not all mobiles have a large screen, and not all of us have sharp eyes. format your data as a text.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize some expression or just evaluate a double summation given values of x and c?

Comment: just evaluate a double summation given values of x and c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.